# Instantiating types using AutoMapper with a DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, castle-windsor

Please see the code below:

```
public class Test : ITest
    {
        public ITest2 _iTest2;
        public int _id;
        public string _name;

        public Test(ITest2 test2)
        {
            _iTest2 = test2;
        }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
    }

    public class Test2 : ITest2
    {
    }

    public interface ITest2
    {

    }

    public class Test3 : ITest3
    {
        public int _id;
        public string _name;
    }

    public interface ITest3
    {

    }
```

I have the following in my Global.asax:

```
Mapper.Initialize(m =>
            {  
 m.CreateMap<DataLayer.Test3, BusinessLayer.Test>().ConstructUsing(opt => new BusinessLayer.Test(new BusinessLayer.Test2()));
});
```

I can map the types in my client app doing this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DataLayer.Test3, BusinessLayer.Test>().ConstructUsing(opt => new BusinessLayer.Test(new BusinessLayer.Test2()));
```

How can I map the types using Castle Windsor instead of having to use the new keyword for Test and Test2?

I read another answer and someone suggested doing this:

```
 public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {

        container.Register(Types.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).BasedOn(typeof(IValueResolver<,,>)));
        // container.Register(Types.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).BasedOn<IValueResolver>());
        container.Register(Types.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<Profile>().WithServiceBase());
        var profiles = container.ResolveAll<Profile>();

        // Add your list of profiles to the mapper configuration here
        Mapper.Initialize(m => {
            m.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);
            profiles.ToList().ForEach(p => m.AddProfile(p));
        });

        // I'm not sure about this as I haven't used AutoMapper for a while,
        // but I assume you want to resolve the static mapper instance
        container.Register(Component.For<IMapper>().Instance(Mapper.Instance));
    }
```

Do I have to do this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DataLayer.Test3, BusinessLayer.Test>().ConstructUsing(opt => new BusinessLayer.Test(new BusinessLayer.Test2()));
```

or should AutoMapper be able to map the types using this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DataLayer.Test3, BusinessLayer.Test>()
```

Comment: What that code is saying is "When you want to create a new service, get it from the Windsor container". Short of using the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) something like this is probably the way to go.

Comment: @stuartd, what AutoMapper configuration is needed to get the code above working i.e. Castle Windsor and AutMapper?

Comment: Sorry it's been too long since I last used Castle to be able to remember off the top of my head..

Comment: @stuartd, can you answer the question in the last five lines of my original pimost?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here? Is this just test code? What are you mapping controllers to controllers for? I've tried this and my test code works fine: https://ibb.co/fOcW4a - that's using the exact `ITest` etc interfaces and classes you've posted. You need `ConstructServicesUsing` which, when mapping, uses a `Func<Type, object>` to attempt to resolve the object from the container (which matches the signature of `IWinsorContainer.Resolve`). The question is - what are you doing and why? Maybe if we had more background we could advise you better...

Comment: @Charleh, the code works.  I want to know if I am approaching it correctly.   I thought the whole point of IOC was that you do not use the NEW keyword.  However, when I create the mapping in my OP (second to last code fragment), I have to use the NEW keyword.

Comment: I am not mapping controllers - I just put some test classes in my controller namespace.

Comment: I don't use the keyword in my snippet above - the point of containers isn't to not use the new keyword, it's to instantiate objects that have their dependencies satisfied - inversion of control. This **does** mostly mean *not* using the `new` keyword, but it really depends on what you are doing with your mappings. If you want a new transient object (or singleton) every time you map something that expects one in the constructor, `ConstructServicesUsing` will work for you, however, it is really mapping specific - can you explain a use case?

Comment: @Charleh, could you post an answer showing how you would solve the Use Case in my question? i.e. map Test3 to Test using Automapper and castle windsor? Your code snippet does not use automapper.  It just uses Castle Windsor to create a type.

Comment: The screenshot above shows the code, the only bit that's missing is registering the 3 interfaces with the container and pointing those registrations against their implementations

Comment: @Charleh, but there is not reference to automapper in your snippet?

Comment: True... Haha ok I'll update when I get back, I'm just at a meal at the moment, going to be a couple of hours

Comment: Thanks.  Yes please do - post an answer so that I can reward credit for your efforts.

Comment: @Charleh, still no closer so looking forward to the snippet update.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148647/automapper-without-the-new-keyword-discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get AutoMapper to use Windsor to create the target type, you need to configure two things:

1. Tell AutoMapper to construct services using Windsor
2. Tell AutoMapper (per-mapping) to actually use the above configuration

   ```
    var container = new WindsorContainer();

       Mapper.Initialize(m =>
       {
           m.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);

           m.CreateMap<Test3, ITest>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator(); // This is important!

       });

       container.Register(Component.For<ITest>().ImplementedBy<Test>());
       container.Register(Component.For<ITest2>().ImplementedBy<Test2>());
       container.Register(Component.For<ITest3>().ImplementedBy<Test3>());

       var test3 = new Test3();
       var test1 = Mapper.Instance.Map<Test3, ITest>(test3);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone requiring this using [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin) 3.6, [prism](/questions/tagged/prism) 7.1 and [automapper](/questions/tagged/automapper) 8.1, this is what worked for me.

In the App.xml.cs file

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
/// other registrations ...

            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMapperProvider, MapperProvider>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(typeof(IMapper), GetMapper(containerRegistry));
 }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function required in order for injection into custom automapper resolvers
        /// </summary>
        private IMapper GetMapper(IContainerRegistry container)
        {
            var mp = container.GetContainer().Resolve<IMapperProvider>(new[] { container });
            return mp.GetMapper();
        }
```

The mapper provider looks like this:

```
public class MapperProvider : IMapperProvider
    {
        private readonly IContainerRegistry _container;

        public MapperProvider(IContainerRegistry container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IMapper GetMapper()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => _container.GetContainer().Resolve(t));
                // any custom profile statement such as
                cfg.AddProfile<MappingSourcesProfile>();
                // ....
            });

            return config.CreateMapper();
        }
    }
```

Now my custom resolvers works, for example:

```
    public class BarcodesResolver : IValueResolver<repo.Book, Book, List<Barcode>>
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public BarcodesResolver(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public List<Barcode> Resolve(repo.Book source, Book destination, List<Barcode> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            repo.BookAttributes groupedAttribs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<repo.BookAttributes>(source.BookAttributes);

            return _mapper.Map<List<repo.Barcode>, List<Barcode>>(groupedAttribs.Barcodes);
        }
    }
```

The hard parts to work out here were how to specify that the containerRegistry needed to be passed into the constructor of the MapperProvider. There may be a better way of doing this but at least this works.

Also arriving at the line `cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => _container.GetContainer().Resolve(t));` was quite obscure as there seem to be few examples out there.